# Execute sybase stored procedure as linked server procedure sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, linked-server, sybase-asa

EDIT

---

**The final goal is to call a stored procedure hosted in sybase with input and output parameters from SQL Server 2008 via Linked Server**

---

I think title is pretty clear.

My goal is to execute a stored procedure hosted in Sybase SQL Anywhere 8 in SQL Server 2008 through the linked server I already created.

Any SQL query made through the linked server is working. 
In addition I was able to execute a function but I don't now how to get the return value like that

```
EXEC ('CALL "dbname"."procedurename"(''param1'', ''param2'', ''param3'')') AT LinkedServerAlias;
```

Thanks 4 all your help!

Mauro

Comment: It could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741175/calling-oracle-stored-procedure-with-output-parameter-from-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to do it by calling

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([LinkedServer], 'SELECT "dbname"."spname"(@p1,@p2, @p3)')
```

I'll add comments and example as soon as I experiment it.

Answer (score 1):

can you use four part naming convention?

like

```
exec LinkedServerName.dbname.dbo.procedurename @param1, @param2, @param3
```

Comment: OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LinkedServerName" returned message "[Sybase][ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Anywhere]Syntax error or access violation: near '1' in ...";[1](?,?,?,?)".

Comment: Only for SQL Server linked servers

Answer (score 0):

4 part object names are valid only for SQL Server linked servers.

You have to have your EXEC inside an OPENQUERY

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([LinkedServer], 'EXEC MyDB.MyScheme.MyProc.spname @p1, @p2, @p3')
```

Now, you can't parametrise OPENQUERY calls so you have use dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000), @linkedsql nvarchar(4000)

SET @sql = 'EXEC MyDB.MyScheme.MyProc.spname ' + CAST(@p1value as int) + ...
SET @linkedsql = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, ''' + @sql + ''')'

EXEC (@linkedsql)
```