# Calling Oracle stored procedure with output parameter from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures, linked-server

I have an Oracle linked server in SQL Server 2008 R2.
I need to execute Oracle stored procedures (with output parameter in first, and input parameter in second procedure):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my1.spGetDate(CurrentDate OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
-- set output parameter, no select statements
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my1.spDeleteOldRecords(CurrentDate IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
-- conditional delete from oracle table, no select statements
END;
```

I didn't found any complete documentation on this question, only simple examples with parameterless select/nonselect procedures, and want to know, how to call these procedures, procedures with select inside, multiparameter procedures with basic parameter types.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should work like this:

```
DECLARE @dateval DATETIME

EXECUTE ('begin my1.spGetDate(?); end;', @dateval OUTPUT) AT ORA_DBLINK_NAME;

EXECUTE ('begin my1.spDeleteOldRecords(?); end;', @dateval) AT ORA_DBLINK_NAME;
```

If you have several parameters, it could look like this:

```
EXECUTE ('begin my1.spProc(?,?,?,?); end;', @param_in_1, @param_in_2, @param_out_3 OUTPUT, @param_out_4 OUTPUT) AT DBLINK_NAME;
```

Comment: Thanks, examples work corretly. Can you add examples with select inside (select only, select and output parameter, etc.).

Comment: What do you mean by "select"? A way of returning the some variables from the SQL Server stored procedure? Or processing the result set of a SELECT run by the Oralce stored procedure?

Comment: I mean procedures with result set.

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible. There seem to be workarounds using some .NET code but I can't help you with that.

Comment: 1. "begin" and "end;" are required as part of the statement. 2. SQL Server linked server properties must have "RPC=True" and RPC Out=True". Holy smokes, searched for hours this morning trying to do this (with INSERT INTO ... RETURNING). Thank you!

Comment: You can return result sets from an Oracle linked server by using [PIPELINED table functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm), but you'll have to wrap the function in a package with some declarations that specify the fields and data types that are to be returned.  It was a pain, but I've done it.  You call it from SQL Server like this: `EXECUTE ('SELECT * FROM TABLE(<SCHEMA>.<PACKAGE>.<FUNCTION>(?))',@Parameter) AT <LINKED_SERVER_NAME>;`

Comment: @Codo

Can I give name of the parameter instead of (**?,?,?,?**). For example, in oracle SP the name of the parameter are -> **fname, lname, regno**, id then it be like:

`EXECUTE ('begin my1.spProc(fname,lname,regno,id); end;', @param_in_1, @param_in_2, @param_out_3 OUTPUT, @param_out_4 OUTPUT) AT DBLINK_NAME;`

I have more than 40 parameters to pass, so better if I specify with param_name.

Comment: @nirav: To the best of my knowledge, that's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use REF CURSOR and declare that cursor as an output variable in oracle. Using Ref Cursor you can retrieve result set from Oracle Stored procedure