# SQL Server Linked server calls Oracle stored procedure returning a result set

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures, resultset, linked-server

I need a simple example of an Oracle stored procedure that returns a result set. I didn't find out how to return the result set to the SQL Server. What I have now is:

On Oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_sessions (cursorParam OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
OPEN cursorParam FOR select * from v$session;
END;
/
```

running on sql plus:

```
variable rc refcursor;
exec OR_WebI_SmartLinkMetrics( :rc );
print rc;
```

On SQL Server it should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LocalOracle, '{CALL sp_sessions(......)');
```

Is this possible?
I was thinking to use temporary tables?

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Without cursor there is an example here:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741175/calling-oracle-stored-procedure-with-output-parameter-from-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx it is not possible to call stored procedures using OPENQUERY, you must use the four-part name, such as...

```
EXEC SeattleSales.master.dbo.xp_msver
```