# INSERT INTO table RETURNING trigger-generated primary key from SQL Server linked server to Oracle (11g)

Tags: sql-server, oracle

**Scenario: get trigger-generated primary key when calling INSERT INTO from SQL Server linked server to Oracle**

Given

1. Oracle 11g table with columns PRIMARY_KEY_ID, FIELD1, FIELD2, CREATE_DATE. Table has "BEFORE INSERT" trigger that selects NEXTVAL from a sequence into PRIMARY_KEY_ID field.
2. SQL Server 2008 R2 with Linked Server to the Oracle database containing the table above.

When I insert a record into the Oracle table, then I want to retrieve the trigger-generated primary key.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure these properties are set on the SQL Server linked server:

   - RPC=True
   - RPC Out=True
2. Execute this code in SQL Server:

   ```
   DECLARE @Field1 NVARCHAR(42);
   DECLARE @Field2 NVARCHAR(42);
   DECLARE @PrimaryKeyValue INT;
   EXECUTE (
       'begin INSERT INTO MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE (
           FIELD1
           ,FIELD2
           ,CREATE_DATE
           )
       VALUES (
           ?
           ,?
           ,sysdate
           ) RETURNING PRIMARY_KEY_ID INTO :PrimaryKeyValue; end;'
       ,@Field1
       ,@Field2
       ,@PrimaryKeyValue OUTPUT
       ) at oracle_linked_server;
   ```

**Notes**

1. **begin** and **end;** are required in the statement.
2. The **@PrimaryKeyValue** variable declared in SQL Server is the same as the **:PrimaryKeyValue** output parameter; Oracle uses a colon prefix for parameters.
3. See [Calling Oracle stored procedure with output parameter from SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13817343/949607), which provided the inspiration for this answer.

Comment: Well blast, can't get the SQL to format as code. Would appreciate an assist if anyone is willing and able...

Comment: In a list you need to indent the code with 8 spaces, not just 4